# Matrix norms / eigenvalues / singular values / another thing

Tags: matrices, norms, eigenvalues

OK, here is what is probably a stupid question.

Let $M$ be a non-symmetric real matrix: for example, the shear matrix 
$\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$.

There are three things we might ask about it:

1. its largest eigenvalue, which in this case is $1$.
2. its largest singular value, or equivalently 
   $\max_{u,v} \langle u, Mv \rangle$ 
   where we maximize over all pairs of unit vectors $u, v$. This is also known as its operator norm; in this case it's $(\sqrt{5}+1)/2 = 1.618...$
3. a third thing, namely
   $\max_v \langle v, Mv \rangle$
   where we maximize over all unit vectors $v$.  In other words, we restrict the previous maximization to the case $u=v$.  In this case, this quantity is $3/2$.

Of course, for symmetric matrices these three things are equal.  But in general they're not.

Does this third thing have a name?  I'm interested in it, for instance, because if 
$dv/dt = M \cdot v$
I want to bound the derivative of $|v|^2$, which is 
$2 \langle v, Mv \rangle$.

thanks,

Cris

Answer (score 7):

this is called the [numerical radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range) of a matrix